# Lilypond: controlling clef and key signature visibility, aligning markup

Tags: lilypond

My effort to create a document with six incipits from different pieces is 
running into a couple of problems. Can anyone help? I am pasting my code 
below (I've reduced the example somewhat for the purposes of asking the question).

Problem 1: How can I hide the clefs and key signatures from the ends of the 
lines? The commands in \score are not behaving as I thought they would based 
on the documentation.

Problem 2: How can I align the text markup to the start of the lines? I want 
"No. 1" etc. left-aligned to the very start of the staff.

Extra query: Does anyone know why using \partial breaks the beaming in the 
measure *preceding* the partial measure? Is there a general fix for this? 
(Short of hard-coding the proper beaming with [ ].)

Any assistance gratefully received!

=========================

```
\version "2.16.2"

notes = {
  \bar""\mark\markup\normalsize{No. 1}
  \clef bass
  \time 6/8
  \key g \major
  \partial 8 \once \stemUp d=8 |
  g( d e) e( c d) |
  \partial 8*5 d g d b g
  \bar""
  \break

  \mark\markup\normalsize{No. 2}
  \clef bass
  \time 3/8
  \key d \minor
  \partial 8 a=8 |
  d,4 bes'8 | 
  \partial 4 cis,4
  \bar""
  \break

  \mark\markup\normalsize{No. 3}
  \clef bass
  \time 3/8
  \key c \major
  \partial 8 g=8 |
  c8 c,16( d e f) |
  \partial 4 g8( a)
  \bar""
  \break

  \mark\markup\normalsize{No. 4}
  \clef bass
  \time 12/8
  \key es \major
  \partial 8 es8 |
  es( d es) bes( c d) es( d es) g( f g) |
  \break

  \mark\markup\normalsize{No. 5}
  \clef bass
  \time 3/8
  %\key c \minor
  \partial 8 g=8 |
  es8. f16 d8 |
  \partial 16*3 es8.
  \bar""
  \break

  \mark\markup\normalsize{No. 6}
  \clef alto
  \time 6/8
  \key d \major
  \partial 8 a='8 |
  << { d,4. e8 fis g |\noBreak
       fis d a' \stemDown a16( g fis g) a8 \stemUp |\noBreak
       d, a d e fis g |\noBreak } \\
     { fis,4. a8 s s |
       d, s8*5 |
       fis8 s s a s s | } \\
     { s2. |
       a8 s8*5 |
       s2. | } >>
  fis'8 d a d,4
}

\score {
  \relative c <<
    \new Staff \notes
    \override Score.TextScript #'font-family = #'sans
    \override Score.RehearsalMark #'font-family = #'sans
    \override Staff.Clef #'break-visibility = #begin-of-line-visible
    \override Staff.Clef #'explicitClefVisibility = #begin-of-line-visible
    \override Staff.TimeSignature #'break-visibility = #begin-of-line-
visible
    \override Staff.KeySignature #'break-visibility = #begin-of-line-visible
    \override Staff.KeySignature #'explicitKeySignatureVisibility = #begin-
of-line-visible
    \override Staff.KeyCancellation #'break-visibility = #all-invisible
    \override Staff.KeyCancellation #'explicitKeySignatureVisibility = #all-
invisible
  >>
  \layout {
  }
}

\paper {
  paper-height = 250\pt%7in=504pt max.
  line-width = 432\pt
  paper-width = 432\pt
  left-margin = 0\pt
  top-margin = 0\pt
  bottom-margin = 0\pt
  indent = 0
  head-separation = 0\pt
  page-top-space = 0\pt
  after-title-space = 0\pt
  before-title-space = 0\pt
  between-system-padding = 0\pt
  between-system-space = 0\pt
  between-title-space = 0\pt
  foot-separation = 0\pt
  ragged-bottom = ##f
  ragged-right = ##t
}

\book {
  #(set-global-staff-size 13)
}

\header {
  tagline = ""%removed
  title = ""
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution to both of your questions:

1) I compiled your code above and the cautionary clefs are already hidden for me. The time signature problems will be solved by using `\set Staff.explicitKeySignatureVisibility = #begin-of-line-visible`.

2) To solve this, you can align the `\mark\markup` texts with clefs, then shift it by an horizontal amount.

Simply replace your `\score` for this one:

```
\score {
  \relative c <<
    \new Staff \notes
    \override Score.RehearsalMark.break-align-symbols = #'(clef) %this will put the \mark\markup texts above the clefs
    \override Score.Clef.break-align-anchor-alignment = #0.3 % %this controls its horizontal displacement. In my test, 0.3 was the ideal value to have the No. x exactly at the beginning of each system
    \override Score.TextScript #'font-family = #'sans
    \override Score.RehearsalMark #'font-family = #'sans
    \override Staff.Clef #'break-visibility = #begin-of-line-visible
    \override Staff.Clef #'explicitClefVisibility = #begin-of-line-visible
    \override Staff.TimeSignature #'break-visibility = #begin-of-line-visible
    \set Staff.explicitKeySignatureVisibility = #begin-of-line-visible % this will do the job with the time signatures
    \override Staff.KeyCancellation #'break-visibility = #all-invisible
    \override Staff.KeyCancellation #'explicitKeySignatureVisibility = #all-invisible
  >>
  \layout {
  }
}
```

About your extra question: I found the following quotation in an old documentation of LilyPond (v2.12):

> The \partial command is intended to be used only at the beginning of a
>   piece. If you use it after the beginning, some odd warnings may occur.

Maybe this is the reason you are encountering these problems with beaming. I would suggest some workaround, as using invisible rests (entered as `sn`, where n is the duration). One other possibility for the beaming problem is to control the beaming manually. It is annoying, but it gets the job done :) Ex: replace the musical content of your No. 1, which is:

```
  \partial 8 \once \stemUp d=8 |
  g( d e) e([ c d)] |
  \partial 8*5 d g d b g
```

for:

```
  \partial 8 \once \stemUp d=8 |
  g( d e) e([ c d)] |
  \partial 8*5 d[ g d] b[ g]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the markup solution! Running version 2.16.2 (on Windows), the clef still appears (small alto clef at end of fifth line); that must be a bug. Anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: Hmm, you are right, the clef still shows (sorry, I overlook it). I think I manage to solve this problem satisfactorily, so I will write a complete answer down below:

Comment: @user2288772 If you agree that my second answer below solves your problem in a better way, then I would delete my first answer (in my opinion it is not completely correct nor solves all the problems in your original question) together with these commentaries here. Please let me know what you think about this.

Answer (score 3):

So the problem here is that you have one single instrumental staff that is being broken down into 6 pieces, and this causes all sorts of problems with clefs, pickup bars, key signatures. Although the workaround I posted above works well (besides for the clefs), the ideal thing is to have to consider each one of your six examples as a small score. Then you can ask LilyPond to print one below each other. Here is a minimal example:

```
A = {c'4 d' e' f'}
B = {\clef bass c2 g c1}
C = {e'4 d' cis' fis' | e' d' cis' }

\score {\new Staff \A}
\score {\new Staff \B}
\markup {This text will be added between the scores...}
\score {\new Staff \C}
```

Which results in:

[image]

Note how the last bar of C has only 3 quarter notes and thus is left opened, without any `\bar ""` command. Also, all problems with clefs, key signatures and pickup bars are vanished now.

And here is your code reworked. I think now it works quite well:

```
\version "2.16.2"

A = {
  \bar""\mark\markup\normalsize{No. 1}
  \clef bass
  \time 6/8
  \key g \major
  \partial 8 \once \stemUp d=8 |
  g( d e) e( c d) |
  d g d b g
}

B = {
  \mark\markup\normalsize{No. 2}
  \clef bass
  \time 3/8
  \key d \minor
  \partial 8 a'8 |
  d,4 bes'8 | 
  cis,4
}

C = {
  \mark\markup\normalsize{No. 3}
  \clef bass
  \time 3/8
  \key c \major
  \partial 8 g'8 |
  c8 c,16( d e f) |
  g8( a)
}

D = {
  \mark\markup\normalsize{No. 4}
  \clef bass
  \time 12/8
  \key es \major
  \partial 8 es8 |
  es( d es) bes( c d) es( d es) g( f g) |
}

E = {
  \mark\markup\normalsize{No. 5}
  \clef bass
  \time 3/8
  %\key c \minor
  \partial 8 g'8 |
  es8. f16 d8 |
  es8.
}

F = {
  \mark\markup\normalsize{No. 6}
  \clef alto
  \time 6/8
  \key d \major
  \partial 8 a''8 |
  << { d,4. e8 fis g |\noBreak
       fis d a' \stemDown a16( g fis g) a8 \stemUp |\noBreak
       d, a d e fis g |\noBreak } \\
     { fis,4. a8 s s |
       d, s8*5 |
       fis8 s s a s s | } \\
     { s2. |
       a8 s8*5 |
       s2. | } >>
  fis'8 d a d,4
}

\score {
  \relative c <<
    \new Staff \A
    \override Score.RehearsalMark.break-align-symbols = #'(clef) %this will put the \mark\markup texts above the clefs
    \override Score.Clef.break-align-anchor-alignment = #0.3 % %this controls its horizontal displacement. In my test, 0.3 was the ideal value to have the No. x exactly at the beginning of each system
    \override Score.TextScript #'font-family = #'sans
    \override Score.RehearsalMark #'font-family = #'sans
  >>
  \layout { }
}

\score {
  \relative c <<
    \new Staff \B
    \override Score.RehearsalMark.break-align-symbols = #'(clef) %this will put the \mark\markup texts above the clefs
    \override Score.Clef.break-align-anchor-alignment = #0.3 % %this controls its horizontal displacement. In my test, 0.3 was the ideal value to have the No. x exactly at the beginning of each system
    \override Score.TextScript #'font-family = #'sans
    \override Score.RehearsalMark #'font-family = #'sans
  >>
  \layout { }
}

\score {
  \relative c <<
    \new Staff \C
    \override Score.RehearsalMark.break-align-symbols = #'(clef) %this will put the \mark\markup texts above the clefs
    \override Score.Clef.break-align-anchor-alignment = #0.3 % %this controls its horizontal displacement. In my test, 0.3 was the ideal value to have the No. x exactly at the beginning of each system
    \override Score.TextScript #'font-family = #'sans
    \override Score.RehearsalMark #'font-family = #'sans
  >>
  \layout { }
}

\score {
  \relative c <<
    \new Staff \D
    \override Score.RehearsalMark.break-align-symbols = #'(clef) %this will put the \mark\markup texts above the clefs
    \override Score.Clef.break-align-anchor-alignment = #0.3 % %this controls its horizontal displacement. In my test, 0.3 was the ideal value to have the No. x exactly at the beginning of each system
    \override Score.TextScript #'font-family = #'sans
    \override Score.RehearsalMark #'font-family = #'sans
  >>
  \layout { }
}

\score {
  \relative c <<
    \new Staff \E
    \override Score.RehearsalMark.break-align-symbols = #'(clef) %this will put the \mark\markup texts above the clefs
    \override Score.Clef.break-align-anchor-alignment = #0.3 % %this controls its horizontal displacement. In my test, 0.3 was the ideal value to have the No. x exactly at the beginning of each system
    \override Score.TextScript #'font-family = #'sans
    \override Score.RehearsalMark #'font-family = #'sans
  >>
  \layout { }
}

\score {
  \relative c <<
    \new Staff \F
    \override Score.RehearsalMark.break-align-symbols = #'(clef) %this will put the \mark\markup texts above the clefs
    \override Score.Clef.break-align-anchor-alignment = #0.3 % %this controls its horizontal displacement. In my test, 0.3 was the ideal value to have the No. x exactly at the beginning of each system
    \override Score.TextScript #'font-family = #'sans
    \override Score.RehearsalMark #'font-family = #'sans
  >>
  \layout { }
}


\paper {
  paper-height = 250\pt%7in=504pt max.
  line-width = 432\pt
  paper-width = 432\pt
  left-margin = 0\pt
  top-margin = 0\pt
  bottom-margin = 0\pt
  indent = 0
  head-separation = 0\pt
  page-top-space = 0\pt
  after-title-space = 0\pt
  before-title-space = 0\pt
  between-system-padding = 0\pt
  between-system-space = 0\pt
  between-title-space = 0\pt
  foot-separation = 0\pt
  ragged-bottom = ##f
  ragged-right = ##t
}

\book {
  #(set-global-staff-size 13)
}

\header {
  tagline = ""%removed
  title = ""
}
```

Producing:

[image]